# How to create a directive in Angular JS for a Morris JS graph

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, angularjs-directive, morris.js

I am trying to create a graph using Morris JS by creating an Angular JS directive. My directive code is:

```
Reporting.directive('morrisLine', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: '<div id="call-chart">test2</div>',
    scope: {
        data: '=', //list of data object to use for graph
        xkey: '=',
        ykey: '='
    },
    link: function(scope,element,attrs){
      new Morris.Line({
          element: element,
          data: [
                { year: '2008', value: 20 },
                { year: '2009', value: 10 },
                { year: '2010', value: 5 },
                { year: '2011', value: 5 },
                { year: '2012', value: 20 }
              ],
          xkey: '{year}',
          ykey: ['value'],
      });
   }
  };
});
```

The Error code I am getting when I check the console on my browser is :

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined
    at Object.t.parseDate (eval at <anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:4904), <anonymous>:1:9523)
    at n.eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:4904), <anonymous>:1:3297)
    at n.t.Grid.r.setData (eval at <anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:4904), <anonymous>:1:3888)
    at n.r (eval at <anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:4904), <anonymous>:1:1680)
    at new n (eval at <anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:4904), <anonymous>:1:11953)
    at link (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/app/directives/directives.js:94:20)
    at j (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js:43:157)
    at e (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js:38:463)
    at e (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js:38:480)
    at e (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js:38:480) <div morris-line="" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope" style="position: relative;">
```

The part the error code is pointing at is the part that says

```
 element : element,
```

I am new to Angular JS and directives and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction of how to deal with this problem. Thank you!

Comment: the error accrued  because the element is undefiend can you please give us the link of the directive library please

Comment: hey I wrote a directive for this, making morris charts with angular: https://github.com/jasonshark/ng-morris/blob/master/src/ngMorris.js It's also available via bower: `bower install ngmorris --save`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

this is how I did with morris chart. Example is barchart:

```
sampleApp.directive('barchart', function() {

    return {

        // required to make it work as an element
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div></div>',
        replace: true,
        // observe and manipulate the DOM
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

            var data = $scope[attrs.data],
                xkey = $scope[attrs.xkey],
                ykeys= $scope[attrs.ykeys],
                labels= $scope[attrs.labels];

            Morris.Bar({
                    element: element,
                    data: data,
                    xkey: xkey,
                    ykeys: ykeys,
                    labels: labels
                });
        }

    };

});
```

then you can use it with this element:

```
<barchart xkey="xkey" ykeys="ykeys" labels="labels" data="myModel"></barchart>
```

where myModel is the array of data to be pass in directive, it should have the proper format to be compatible with morris charts. take a close look on how this object is being pass in "link" function in the directive.

Here is a working and complete example: http://jsbin.com/ayUgOYuY/5/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Could it be that observe doesn't work correctly in this example?

Comment: @AxelFontaine: Hi, What you mean that observe doesn't work correctly? We can still just remove the observe in the code and just place Morris instance outside the function. It still works. IMHO, Best use of observe to watch data changes over time. mostly in live updates.

Comment: Ok, I finally have it all working. You need an element.empty() if you use something like  $scope.$watchCollection(attrs.data, setData);

Comment: glad you sort it out! :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change

```
 xkey: '{year}',
 ykey: ['value'],
```

to

```
xkey: 'year',
ykeys: ['value'],
```